# Why are my animations getting out of sync?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a problem. I need a little help.
I need to synchronize both animations. The slider and the typing animation, but I can't do it.
When the user is on the tab it works great, but when he goes to the other tab and comes back to the page, something goes wrong and the animation is out of sync, I don't know why. Probably the slider is trying to make up for the time the user was on another tab.
Can anyone help me?
Thanks a lot!

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const carousel = document.querySelector('.carousel');
  const slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
  let slideWidth = slides[0].offsetWidth;
  let centerOffset = (carousel.offsetWidth - slideWidth) / 2;
  let currentCenterIndex = 2;
  let intervalId;
  const carouselPeriod = parseInt(carousel.getAttribute('data-period')) || 7600;

  function updateSlideWidth() {
    slideWidth = slides[0].offsetWidth;
    centerOffset = (carousel.offsetWidth - slideWidth) / 2;
  }

  function goToSlide(index) {
    const slideOffset = centerOffset - slideWidth * index;
    carousel.style.transform = `translateX(${slideOffset}px)`;
    currentCenterIndex = index;

    slides.forEach((slide, i) => {
      if (i === currentCenterIndex) {
        slide.classList.add('color-slide');
      } else {
        slide.classList.remove('color-slide');
      }
    });
  }

  function nextSlide() {
    if (currentCenterIndex < slides.length - 1) {
      goToSlide(currentCenterIndex + 1);
    } else {
      currentCenterIndex = 0;
      goToSlide(currentCenterIndex);
    }
  }

  function startCarousel() {
    intervalId = setInterval(nextSlide, carouselPeriod);
  }


  startCarousel();
  function handleResize() {
    updateSlideWidth();
    goToSlide(currentCenterIndex);
  }
  updateSlideWidth();
  window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);


  class TxtType {
    constructor(el, toRotate, period) {
      this.toRotate = toRotate;
      this.el = el;
      this.loopNum = 0;
      this.period = parseInt(period, 10) || 1000;
      this.txt = '';
      this.totalTime = 9000;
      this.timePerChar = this.totalTime / (this.toRotate.join('').length * 2);
      this.isDeleting = false;
      this.animationComplete = false;
      this.tick();
    }
    tick() {
      var i = this.loopNum % this.toRotate.length;
      var fullTxt = this.toRotate[i];

      if (this.isDeleting) {
        this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length - 1);
      } else {
        this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length + 1);
      }

      this.el.innerHTML = '<span class="wrap">' + this.txt + '</span>';

      var that = this;
      var delta = this.isDeleting ? this.timePerChar / 2 : this.timePerChar;

      if (!this.isDeleting && this.txt === fullTxt) {
        delta = this.period - this.timePerChar * fullTxt.length;
        this.isDeleting = true;
      } else if (this.isDeleting && this.txt === '') {
        this.isDeleting = false;
        this.loopNum++;
        delta = 500;
      }

      if (!this.isDeleting && this.txt === fullTxt) {
        delta = this.period - this.timePerChar * fullTxt.length;
        this.isDeleting = true;
        this.animationComplete = true;
      }

      setTimeout(function () {
        that.tick();
      }, delta);
    }
  }
  


  function write() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('typewrite');
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      var toRotate = elements[i].getAttribute('data-type');
      var period = elements[i].getAttribute('data-period');
      if (toRotate) {
        new TxtType(elements[i], JSON.parse(toRotate), period);
      }
    }
  };
  write();
});
```

```css
.carousel-container {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
  }

.carousel {
    display: flex;
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out !important; 
}

.slide img {
    width: 384px;
    height: 305px;
    filter: grayscale(1);
    transition: scale 1.4s;
    scale: .7;
}

.color-slide img {
    filter: grayscale(0);
    scale: .9;
    opacity: 1;
}

.thanks_for_support {
    color: #000;
    text-align: center; 
}



.typewrite > .wrap {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.typewrite > .wrap::after {
    content: '';
    height: 100%;
    width: 3px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -2%;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    animation: closeBar 1.6s infinite .7s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="thanks_for_support">
<h4 style="min-height: 68px;">THanks: <br/><a href=""><span class="text typewrite" data-period="7000" data-type='["TETEE", "ESTC", "TESTB", "TESTA", "WA", "DDDDDDDDD" ,"ZZZZZZ" ,"XXXXXXXXXX"]'></span></a></h4>
</div>
<div class="carousel-container">
<div class="carousel" data-period="7600">
  <div class="slide">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1531804055935-76f44d7c3621?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=688&q=80" alt="">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508921912186-1d1a45ebb3c1?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=687&q=80" alt="">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="slide color-slide">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://plus.unsplash.com/premium_photo-1664457233806-e1477e52e2ab?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=765&q=80" alt="">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1554080353-a576cf803bda?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=687&q=80" alt="">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1495231916356-a86217efff12?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=736&q=80" alt="">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1566275529824-cca6d008f3da?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=687&q=80" alt="">
    </a>
</div>
  <div class="slide">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1457089328109-e5d9bd499191?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=663&q=80" alt="">
    </a>
</div>
  <div class="slide">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1482482097755-0b595893ba63?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=688&q=80" alt="">
    </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: If you leave it long enough even without going elsewhere and coming back it gets out of sync, so that fact might make it easier to debug.

Comment: @AHaworth Ok, but how can i fix it?